# HttpError: Invalid bucket name, on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I wanted to create a google cloud function triggered by an HTTP request to open a file stored in google cloud storage. I need to use HTTP trigger instead of cloud storage event-triggered because I need to pass some parameters according to which the file will be modified.

To access google cloud storage I use this **code**(Inside cloud function):

```py
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client(project='auto-ml-and-explainable-ai')
bucket_name = 'feature_engineering_dataset'
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
```

**But I got the Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gcsfs/retry.py", line 115, in retry_request
    return await func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gcsfs/core.py", line 384, in _request
    validate_response(status, contents, path, args)
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.9/site-packages/gcsfs/retry.py", line 102, in validate_response
    raise HttpError(error)
gcsfs.retry.HttpError: Invalid bucket name: '<Bucket: feature_engineering_dataset>', 400
```

But the storage bucket with the same name is present in the GCP project. I also checked using the local service account credential file, it is working fine,

**Code**

```py
from google.cloud import storage
storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('/Users/auto-ml-and-explainable-ai.json')
bucket_name = 'feature_engineering_dataset'
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
```

**Output**

```
<Bucket: feature_engineering_dataset>
```

What Should I do?

Comment: probably I would start with -  a storage client constructor without parameters, and check that the service account used by your cloud function has relevant IAM permissions the the bucket access.

Comment: but the code I have written in the cloud function itself, it has service account permission `auto-ml-and-explainable-ai@appspot.gserviceaccount.com` and I have some other function which triggers from storage event can access the bucket with same service account permission.